# VPN set up through cmd

Tags: java, windows, console, cmd, vpn

I am looking for a way to create a new VPN connection using only the command line. All I see in Google searches are how to connect to an existing VPN connection, which is through rasdial. Thanks.

Comment: What has this got to do with Java?

Comment: I was hoping to execute the command line through java. If there are any APIs I can use that can allow me to directly create a VPN connection in Java, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [use RAS API directly from Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764032.aspx).

If you want to create VPN connection from pure CMD, I'd try to append connection info to rasphone.pbk file in user's profile (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`).

For more ideas see [How can I programmatically create a Windows VPN connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318233/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-windows-vpn-connection)

Comment: I think the link you gave me with regards to the other question in stackoverflow states a solution in C#. Is it possible to use C# libraries in Java?

Comment: I am not a Java developer, but I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420617/accessing-net-dll-libraries-components-from-java

Answer (score 0):

Cisco VPN can connect using the Command line.You can create your own script files that use the CLI commands to perform routine tasks, such as connect to a corporate server, run reports, and then disconnect from the server. 
To display a list of all VPN Client commands, go to the directory that contains the VPN Client software, and enter the vpnclient command at the command-line prompt: 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client46/administration/guide/vcAch5.html

Comment: Is this any different from the VPN that comes with Windows?