# Connect to Always-On VPN using C#

Tags: c#, vpn

This is my first time writing a post, so bear with me.

I've made a program for my work and have been asked to implement a feature in it now, where our users are able to connect to our VPN (Always-On VPN), using the program.
However, I don't seem to be able to find any information on how to actually establish the connection programmatically. I need to basically be able to click on a button that says "Connect to VPN" and it will then establish the connection, much like it does in Windows when clicking connect:

[Clicking Connect in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwE7f.png)

I've figured out how to see if the connection is established or not via my program:

```
    public bool CheckForVPNInterface()
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (NetworkInterface @interface in interfaces)
            {
                if (@interface.Description.Contains("Always-On VPN") && @interface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    Label_Connection.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    Label_Connection.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            
        }
        return false;    
    }
```

But now just need to have the "Connect to VPN" button.

Any idea on how to do so?

NOTE: I've tried using rasdial, but that didn't work

Comment: if this is a true Always-On-VPN-Connection, establishing it can be triggered by simply trying to access a resource behind the VPN, e.g. pinging a known file server. If this is a regular VPN connection, rasdial should work. Probably without username and password, because authentication is usually done via certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find much info on the subject, but I found this obscure Windows API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/get_connected/getvpnconnected

Edit: [maybe this will also help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318233/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-windows-vpn-connection)